# mongodb->sorting inside documents

Tags: php, mongodb

I have this structure per document:

```
{
"_id": NumberInt(781),
"link_id": {
 "11617": {
   "thumb_position": NumberInt(654),
   "last_scan": NumberInt(1362671892),
   "row_numb": NumberInt(0),
   "clicks": NumberInt(0)
},
 "11623": {
   "thumb_position": NumberInt(562),
   "last_scan": NumberInt(1362671892),
   "row_numb": NumberInt(0),
   "clicks": NumberInt(0)
},
 "11689": {
   "thumb_position": NumberInt(93),
   "last_scan": NumberInt(1362671892),
   "row_numb": NumberInt(0),
   "clicks": NumberInt(0)
}, {...}
}
```

the fact is I want to order this by thumb_position. I am using:
     $res = $collection->find(array("_id" => intval(781)))->sort(array('link_id.thumb_position' => 1))

It is not working. I've tried ->sort(array('link_id.$.thumb_position' => 1)) or ->sort(array('thumb_position' => 1)) and the corresponding $collection->ensureIndex. No luck. 
I have seen some examples of sorting but they are all related to sorting documents, and no sorting inside the document.
Any ideas?!
Thx a lot!

Comment: you could use asort on the array when you get it back, this is probably faster than doing it through the aggregation framework unless you wanna extra ops on it after

Comment: thx for u r answer! so, doing it in php is faster than in mongodb?

Comment: Most likely for this case, PHP can do a instant quick sort here while MongoDB would have to do a unwind which is more costly.